# Guess the last pattern in the image

Tags: pattern

Find the last pattern in the picture and state your reasons.

source: zoomit.ir

[image]

Comment: Did you make this image? If not are you allowed to copy it here?

Comment: no i didn't i just saw it before, and it was a question to me, and as far as i know there is no problem to copy a link

Comment: You haven't given a link or even any attribution.

Comment: If we have to guess the answer, I'm pretty sure it doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: Looks like it was copied from [puzzles.com](http://www.puzzles.com/PuzzlePlayground/NextSquare/NextSquare.htm), after removing the copyright notice.

Comment: it belongs to zoomit.ir i'm adding the link

Comment: What do mean symbols under the answer options?

Comment: there are numbers from 1 to 5 in another language, not important in this question.

Comment: -1 For excessive question bumping.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is the 5th one
All we have here is the numbers written in the right side of the square with the lines overlapping the box

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Pattern puzzles like this aren't the best because there can be so many answers.  For example, I say that none of the supplied choices are the next item.

For one thing, the color pattern is *clearly* going to repeat red, yellow, blue, green, so the next square should be red, but all the choices are yellow!
Also, the squares in the odd positions all should have just one line, with one endpoint at the center of the square.  Again, none of the choices match this!  The single line is just a simple rotation of 45 degrees clockwise, so the next square should be a red square with a line from the center to the bottom right corner.

Now, I can think of two different options for the square after that.  Keeping with the color pattern, it will be yellow.  One way to go from the second square to the fourth is to rotate the line that is furthest clockwise 135 degrees counterclockwise.  If that's the case, the 6th square will have two lines from the center of the square to the two top corners.
The other way could be to rotate the furthest clockwise line 90 degrees counterclockwise, and the other line only 45 degrees counterclockwise.  If that's the case, the 6th square will have just one line from the center to the top of the square.

[image]

Comment: the second box is orange... they attempted (and failed) to make all boxes noticably different colors.

Comment: I think the color is just for fun, ans the answers are all the same color

Comment: Ah but they gave us colors so I am using them!  But colors or no, there's logic for the lines other than the puzzle's intended solution.

Comment: I would have picked orange for the final color as it appears to be bouncing along ROYGB if you move from outer to inner.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you move from outer to inner?"  The puzzle only supplied the first four terms in the pattern, so where do you get 5 colors from?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is number 4.

Box 4 is  a combination of boxes 1 and 3.
The fifth box should be a combination of boxes 2 and 4.

Hence the fifth box is to be filled with answer 4.

This also explains the lack of a discernible pattern to boxes 1 through 3.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Your answer is valid, though there is already another (accepted) answer which seems to fit better. Don't you think so?

Comment: $(+1)$ This is what I first thought :)